# saving output and ListPlot the output:

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, output-formatting, data

Let's say I have

```
x = 1; y = 2;

d = x^2 + y^5 ;
```

and

```
x = 5; y = 3;

d = x^2 + y^5 ;
```

and

```
x = 8; y = 5;

d = x^2 + y^5;
```

and

```
x = 6; y = 24;
d = x^2 + y^5;
```

and

```
x = 12; y = 0;
d = x^2 + y^5;
```

now, is there any way I can save the values of d for given x and y and plot it in ListPlot, without using Loop/Table/Map/NesteList etc.

I do not want to use loop/Table/Map/NestedList and then stored (by using Reap and Sow) the values in d and ListPlot. The reason is that I am trying to make GUI and the original equation is PDE and using FEM. So, the memoryuse is too much.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way could be:

```
pts = {{1, 2}, {5, 3}, {8, 5}, {6, 24}, {12, 0}};
res = {First@#, Last@#, (First@#)^2 + (Last@#)^5} & /@ pts
Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[res, PlotStyle -> Red]
 , ListPlot3D[res, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1]]
 ]
```

---

[image]

---

Or you could define a function:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^5;
res2 = Transpose[Transpose[pts]~Join~{f @@@ pts}]
```